# IIS rewrite rule with HTTP status code 301

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, url-rewrite-module

```
I need to write a IIS rewrite rule which matches the following condition
```

1. example.com
2. www.example.com
3. http://www.example.com
4. https://www.example.com
5. http://example.com
6. https://example.com

   this all should redirect to https://www.example.com/somepage/

   The condition is that from SEO point of view only one 301 redirection should be identified. Any pointer is appreciated

Following redirection were tried works but leads to two hops instead of one

```
    <rule name="no path" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/?$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.com$" ignoreCacom="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/somepage" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="with path and http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/somepage" negate="true" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/.+$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.com$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="with path and https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/somepage" negate="true" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/.+$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="with somepage, no www" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/somepage" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" ignoreCacom="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="with somepage and https, no www" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="\/somepage" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" ignoreCacom="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: please give a solid effort before posting. this doesnt contain any code, leading the viewer to believe you didnt try at all.

Comment: @CodingNinja Thanks , edited the post to contain the rules which were tried

Comment: Adding this condiction, seems to have done the trick 
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these rules achieve your requirement?
With this rule order. http(s)://(www.)example.com/a.aspx with path will be redirected to https://www.example.com/a.aspx

https://www.example.com/a.aspx will not be redirected to avoid infinite redirection loop.

http(s)://(www.)example.com/  will be redirected to https://www.example.com/somepage.

Since it is impossible to merge everything into a rule. We need at least 3 rule to achieve this.

```
   <rule name="https://www.example.com">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.+$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="no path" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/somepage/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="with path" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/.+$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/somepage" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://wwww.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: @Ding : Thanks 
These rules almost works , just that urls like https://www.example.com/styles/css/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.css end up in "Too many redirects"